# How exactly does JavaScript perform memory allocation during evaluation process?

Tags: javascript, memory

I know that JavaScript is a dynamic type language and executes programs divided by evaluation and execution processes. And JavaScript registers variables in the Lexical environment of the execution context during the evaluation process, and allocates the actual value while executing the allocation statement during the execution process.

Here I was wondering how JavaScript allocates memory for each variable during the evaluation process.

Because it's before JavaScript evaluate the type, is JavaScript allocating it to a certain byte size and keeping each of them away?

I could find many articles about JavaScript's memory management, but I couldn't figure out how the allocation occurred in the beginning.

Is there any way I can know this?

Answer (score -1):

AFAIK it will use the stack for everything that has a known size and for the rest it uses the heap.

I found this article useful.

https://felixgerschau.com/javascript-memory-management/#the-memory-heap-and-stack

Comment: I could see how JavaScript allocated primitive values. Thank you.

I understood that the object registers the memory address in the heap and assigns the primitive value inside to the stack. Can I guess that both the primitive value in the object and primitive value are compiled without any difference and stacked?

Comment: Not really. In stack javascript stores static data like: numbers, strings, booleans, undefined and null. So the ones for which we know the size from the start. All other things like objects, functions are stored in heap. 
This means that the whole object is stored in the heap. The only think that is stored in the stack regarding to it is a reference (because we have to be able to access it somehow)

Comment: The article above has a great visual example: https://felixgerschau.com/static/b452488bd7eeac0405c48f164da6280d/5a190/stack-heap-pointers.png

Comment: I was completely mistaken. Now I totally understand. Thank you so much. :)